# How to make Mac's mouse icon to be left hand friendly?

Tags: macos, mouse, icon

I'm left handed and want to have a mouse icon that pointed to top right corner instead of to left. In Windows I've made my own mouse theme to achieve that. Then how about Mac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following app called Mousecape:

https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases/tag/0.0.5

After downloading, installing both the app and the helper app, do the following:

1. Go to the Mousecape preferences and choose “I am left handed”.
2. Dump the system cursors into a cape from the menu: “Capes” → “Dump
   Cursors”
3. Apply the Cursor Dump cape (right click → apply)

Done!

Comment: I have searched a lot and only you solved my problem, thanks dude!

Comment: @Elderry happy to help :)

Comment: Each time I reboot the setting will be reset, is there a fix for this?